# Manipular elemento de lista com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de uma dica para fazer com que ao clicar na lista, ele acene a pergunta correta e acene a errada, ou só a certa se a pessoa acertou,

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h2>Simulado Detran – Prova Teórica com Gabarito e Respostas</h2>

<div class="questao">Questão</div>

<div class="pergunta"> <p>1&ordm; Pergunta do Simulado</p>
</div>

<div class="respostas">

<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item1" id="1" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone"></div>Resposta 1 da Primeira Pergunta</a>
   
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item2" id="2" id="item2" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone2"></div>Resposta 2 da Primeira  Pergunta</a>
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item3" id="3" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone3"></div>Resposta 3 da Primeira Pergunta</a>
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item4" id="4" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone4"></div>Resposta 4 da Primeira Pergunta</a> <input type="hidden" name="resposta" id="resposta" value="4" />
</div>

<script>
//$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
//$('.item3').addClass('list-group-item-success');
//});
var qtdCarrinho = $("#resposta").val();
//alert(qtdCarrinho);

function recebeResposta(id){
 
 $('this.id').addClass('list-group-item-success');
}
</script>


</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Luciano! Coloca o teu código na pergunta como texto. Se quisermos dar um exemplo é mais fácil e não temos de escrever o código à mão.

Comment: Editado amigo, estou quebrando a cabeça pra conseguir o resultado desejado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta resposta é um modelo funcional, você pode customizá-la da forma que desejar:

**Obs.:** criei uma class `.list-group-item-error` como exemplo apenas para estilizar os itens errados.

```js
var qtdCarrinho = $("#resposta").val();

function recebeResposta(id){
 if(qtdCarrinho == id){
  alert("Resposta Correta!");
  $("#"+id).addClass('list-group-item-success');
 }else{
  alert("Você errou!\nA resposta correta é a "+qtdCarrinho);
  $(".list-group-item:not(.list-group-item[id="+qtdCarrinho+"])").addClass("list-group-item-error");
  $(".list-group-item[id="+qtdCarrinho+"]").addClass("list-group-item-success");
 }
  }
```

```css
.list-group-item-error{
 color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h2>Simulado Detran – Prova Teórica com Gabarito e Respostas</h2>

<div class="questao">Questão</div>

<div class="pergunta"> <p>1&ordm; Pergunta do Simulado</p>
</div>

<div class="respostas">

<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item1" id="1" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone"></div>Resposta 1 da Primeira Pergunta</a>
   
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item2" id="2" id="item2" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone2"></div>Resposta 2 da Primeira  Pergunta</a>
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item3" id="3" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone3"></div>Resposta 3 da Primeira Pergunta</a>
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item item4" id="4" onclick="recebeResposta( this.id )"><div class="icone4"></div>Resposta 4 da Primeira Pergunta</a> <input type="hidden" name="resposta" id="resposta" value="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: FUNCIONOU, muito obrigado amigo, apenas essa linha nao pegou, mas ja tenho o q preciso graça a vc, o resto eu consigo, Obrigado